# Most efficient way to get all types in AppDomain marked with a specific attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection

If I do this, I enumerate over all types in my program:

```
List<SerializableAttribute> attributes=new List<SerializableAttribute>() ;
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        attributes.AddRange(
                            type.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                            .OfType<SerializableAttribute>()
                            .ToList());
    }
}
```

Is metadata that comes with a .NET dll indexed to allow me to do something like:

```
List<SerializableAttribute> attributes = typeof(SerializableAttribute)
                                         .GetClassesIAmDefinedOn();
```

Is there another option that I'm not considering?

(SerializableAttribute is just an example)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Setting `[InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` everywhere?

Comment: I'm not trying to change any attribute values. I'm maintaining a system (that I didn't write) and it's scanning all types for specific attributes to display them somehow in a list in the system, like DisplayNameAttribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient thing to use here *generally* is `Attribute.IsDefined(...)`, although *in the specific case of `[Serializable]`*, `type.IsSerializable` is faster (it isn't actually stored as an attribute in this one case - it has special handling in the compiler, mapping to a CLI flag).

Comment: Do I have to do a "foreach(type in appdomain) { ... Attribute.IsDefined(type) ... }" or is there a way I can do it without enumerating over all types?

Comment: @Mick yes you have to enumerate over the types.

Answer (score 9):

Well, using LINQ more and using `IsDefined` as least makes the code *nicer* (and fetches the types, not the attributes...)

```
var types = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
             from type in assembly.GetTypes()
             where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(SerializableAttribute))
             select type).ToList();
```

Now, you asked about *efficiency* - how long does this take? How long is it *acceptable* for it to take? Are you calling this often? (That would seem odd.)

Also note that it only includes the assemblies which have already been loaded - there could be a referenced assembly which hasn't been loaded yet; does it matter that that isn't picked up?

Comment: This may only take <50/100 ms for a 20K+ type program, but I was really wondering whether the metadata had some sort of cache on it that would prevent me from having to enumerate over all 20K+ types in ANY fashion (for a sub 10ms lookup).

Comment: @Mick the only way to do that would be to explicitly store that data separately.

Comment: @Marc is that even worth considering? i.e. is it as simple as flipping some obscure flag or writing <10 lines of code (that I will never touch again) to change the compilation process?

Comment: Thx. Jon... this worked well.  The one trick you may want to also provide, or let's just mention it here... if you're only caring about the class that you tagged with the Attribute, and not any of it's descendants, you should use the 3rd parameter to IsDefined, and pass false.

Comment: @RichardB: I think I'll leave that in your comment - I don't want to go into *too* much detail :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. And beware GetCustomAttributes. It's very expensive and not cached effectively. AppDomain.Current.Domain.GetAssemblies is also very expensive.

To do things like this, I keep a cache in a Dictionary

```
var cache = new Dictionary<Assembly,Attribute[]>();

foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    var attributes = new List<SerializableAttribute>();
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        attributes.AddRange(
                            type.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                            .OfType<SerializableAttribute>()
                            .ToList());
    }
    cache[assembly] = attributes.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do either:

```
var assem = // get assembly:
var types = assem.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsDefined(typeof(SerializableAttribute)));
```

Or, if you want to do it the other way round:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> WhereDefinedOn(this Type type, IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    if (!typeof(Attribute).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only attribute types are supported.");

    return types.Where(t => t.IsDefined(type));
}
```

Which you can use as:

```
var allTypes = assem.GetTypes();
var filteredTypes = typeof(SerializableAttribute).WhereDefinedOn(allTypes);
```