# C# make class auto-register

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have a number of types for which I need to provide custom functions that talk to the external world.
For example, I may have a Widget, and a Sprocket, and when data from the world that I don't control arrives and says "make a Widget," then I need to call a Widget.Create() function.
If the world says "make a Hammer," then I need to return a "Hammer does not exist" error.
However, the mapping between world-representation and type-name is not 1:1, so I can't simply use reflection to find the type name directly -- I need a table. (In fact, "name" may for example be a specific integer value.)

I understand how I can use a pre-defined table (or Dictionary) that maps from world-representation to class-name.
I also understand how to extend/change this table at runtime if the set of possible classes changes. (Because of rules changes, or dynamically loaded parts of the application, or whatever.)

However, all of that requires duplication -- I have to both implement my class, and then, in some other place in the code, remember to add an instance of "this class has this name in the external world."
This is a bit of a code smell, because sometime in the future I will write a new class (or delete an old class) and forget to update the table, and then spend time debugging why it doesn't work right.

I thought I could use a static member in each class which registers itself in a global table:

```
public static Registration Me = new Registration(typeid(MyClass), "My Name");
```

Unfortunately, static fields are not initialized until some function in the class is executed/accessed, so this doesn't run at start-up. (Static constructors have similar limitations, plus even more overhead in the runtime!)

The next idea was to decorate the class with a custom attribute that says "register this class in the table."

```
[Register("My Name")]
class MyClass : .... {
}
```

Unfortunately, the "Register" attribute doesn't know what class it is attached to -- only the MyClass class knows that it has the Register attribute. (This is infuriating to me, as it would be SO CONVENIENT if attributes knew where they were attached, in many, many cases. But that's an aside!)

So, the least bad implementation I can think of is to iterate all the types of all the assemblies, using reflection, and check whether they have this attribute, and if they do, register them in the table. This is, shall we say, neither elegant nor efficient.

Is there a better way to auto-register classes without having to update some other source file with a central registry?

Comment: Why not one of the many IoC frameworks (many have auto-registration, albeit that is called by "something")? Also there are more component/discovery frameworks like MEF.

Comment: You are not telling how or where or when you are going to "autoregister" your classes but you might find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692781/most-efficient-way-to-get-all-types-in-appdomain-marked-with-a-specific-attribut

Comment: I want to auto-register at program start-up, and if I every dynamically load more assemblies, at time of load (or right after.)
My current solution is to iterate through all the assemblies, iterate through all the types, look for the annotation, register. That is less efficient and less elegant than I'd like.
I'm not looking for an external framework unless it does ONLY auto-discover, and does it more efficiently than what I suggest above. I'm looking for a language technique that would make auto-discovery elegant and efficient.

Comment: Also: Why the down-vote? I'm asking for a particular language construct that would be very useful, and I can't find through Googling (it may be that it doesn't exist.) I show what I've done. How should the question be improved?

Comment: I was looking for something like this myself; in c/cpp you would just have a static in a file like RegisterMe and all the statics in every file would get called and initialised first. Really nice feature I thought, and useful for plug-in type designs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with other resources (that are quite knowledgeable about the internals of the CLR and IL) and it seems that this is a hole in the CLR and the C# language. There simply is no direct way of making things automatically happen on assembly load or appdomain preparation. Walking the types and finding the types that I'm interested in is the least bad way.
In fact, attributes aren't always created until some piece of code asks for them, so I can't use an attribute constructor with a type argument to auto-register, either!

This is of course not great, because if there are eight different pieces of code that each have their own kind of registration they want to do, each of those pieces have to iterate through all of the types and do the inspection on their own. The only way around that would be to give up on modularity, and make all of the different "things" that happen to types be centralized to a single walk-all-types loop at the start of the app. Third party libraries (including the MEF) still wouldn't go inside this loop, though, so there's just an unavoidable chunk of overhead here, OR an unavoidable piece of duplication -- my choice, as developer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also iterate over all classes matching some criteria and use `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor` to ensure the static initializers all get run.

Something like:

```
var baseType = typeof(MyType);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
foreach (var t in types)
{
    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(t.TypeHandle);
}
```

This should ensure all your

```
public static Registration Me = new Registration(typeid(MyClass), "My Name");
```

functions get called.